# How to convert a system of non-linear XOR equations to CNF

Tags: nonlinear-functions, sat-solvers, stream-cipher

I'm trying to analyse phase shift fault analysis in trivium and came across a system of non-linear equations to solve. I read about sat-solvers and Gaussian elimination but unfortunately, none of the articles I found on the internet shows how to tackle a non-linear system of equations with a large number of variables (here trivium gives 288 variables). So I'm pretty much stuck now on how to solve for these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could express your problem as a network of Boolean gates - a netlist - and use [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) to translate it to CNF. You can instruct `bc2cnf` to output `XOR` clauses in `XCNF` format, an extended `CNF` format with "x" clauses denoting `XOR` clauses.

SAT solvers like [cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat) are capable of reading `XCNF` and/or detecting the contained `XOR` gates and performing Gaussian elimination. Cryptominisat [reportedly](https://www.google.com/search?q=trivium+cryptominisat) has been used several times to attack the [Trivium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium_(cipher)) stream cipher.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at an SMT solver, e.g. Z3.  With SMT you can express Boolean equations and inequalities in a natural way instead of bit-blasting everything down to a SAT instance.  There's plenty of documentation online to get you started.